# How to send a last message and close the socket when a SwiftUI view is dismissed?

Tags: swift, swiftui, deinit, network-framework

I have a *SwiftUI* sheet view with an *ObservedObject* that handles tcp communication, when this sheet gets dismissed I need it to send a last tcp message and then close the socket. The *onDisappear* event never seems to get triggered (**Edit: found out the culprit its because I'm presenting the sheet using a *UIHostingController*, still need a solution**) I've tried putting it I the form, navigation view, tried creating a new stack for it, nothing worked. So I've tried using my *ObservedObject* deinit but this gives me a bad access error if I try to reopen the view fast after closing it.

```
deinit {
    let msg = getUpdatedTimersString()
    self.connection.sendMsg(msg, success: connection.close)
}
```

from my connection class that uses `Network Framework`

```
func sendMsg(_ message: String, success: @escaping () -> Void = { }, error: @escaping () -> Void = { }) {
        let msg = message + "\r\n"
        let data: Data? = msg.data(using: .utf8)
        debugPrint("Sending: \(msg)")
        connection.send(content: data, completion: .contentProcessed { (sendError) in
            if let sendError = sendError {
                self.debug("\(sendError)")
                error()
            } else {
                success()
            }
        })
}

func close() {
        connection.cancel()
}
```

Edit: adding the view code below

```
struct ScheduleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var scheduleManager = ScheduleManager() // This handles the tcp communication, the deinit you see above is from this

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(scheduleManager.timers) { timer in
                    ScheduleForm(scheduleManager: self.scheduleManager, timer: timer).onDisappear { debugPrint("schedule form row disappeared") } // This is just a view that adds a section header and a DatePicker to the form for each timer
                }
            }.onDisappear { debugPrint("form disappeared") }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Schedule"), displayMode: .inline)
        }.onDisappear() { debugPrint("nav disappeared") }
    }
}
```

None of these *onDisappear* work for me, the one in the *ScheduleForm*  rows is the only one that even triggers for me, but it triggers when the sheet is created and every time I scroll a row out of sight, but not when I dismiss the sheet.

Comment: What dismisses the view? Is it connected to some binding above it?

Comment: You need to show your sheet view, where you call onDisappear

Comment: @jnblanchard its sheet view that can be dismissed through a swipe

Comment: @ErnistIsabekov I just updated it with the view code

Comment: View cod looks ok onDisappear should trigger when swipe down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
final class ScheduleController: UIHostingController<ScheduleView> {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: ScheduleView())
    }

    init() {
        super.init(rootView: ScheduleView())
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        rootView.scheduleManager.updateTimers() // this sends the last message
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        rootView.scheduleManager.connection.close // this closes the connection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did was change your function signature to use a single closure for success and error completion.

```
func sendMsg(_ message: String, completion: ((Bool) ->())? = nil)
```

Then we can use that inside the onDisappear modifier. On completion close the connection.

```
struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {

    Text("Hello World").onDisappear {
      sendMsg("last msg", completion: { completed in
        close()
      })
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I would check everything on exception and return error message if got

Comment: The onDisappear event just isn't working properly for me at all, I'm using Xcode 11.3.1. Does it trigger for you when the sheet is dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

what I often do is something like this:

```
struct ScheduleView: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

@ObservedObject var scheduleManager = ScheduleManager() 

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            ForEach(scheduleManager.timers) { timer in
                ScheduleForm(scheduleManager: self.scheduleManager, timer: timer)
            }
        }
    }.onDisappear(perform: doExit)
     .navigationBarTitle(Text("Schedule"), displayMode: .inline)
}

func doExit() {

  // do your closing etc ... here

  // then to go back to the previous view
  self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```

}

Comment: .onDisappear never triggers for me when the sheet is swiped away, could it be because I'm using a UIHostingController ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this very crude test working. 
A sheet is presented and when you swipe, onDisappear is triggered and perform the doExit function. Don't know anything about UIHostingController.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var testArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
@State var showMe = false

var body: some View {
    Button(action: { self.showMe = true}) {
        Text("Press button")
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showMe, onDismiss: {self.showMe = false}) { TestView(scheduleManager: self.testArray) }
}
}

struct TestView: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
@State var scheduleManager: [String]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            ForEach(scheduleManager, id: \.self) { timer in
                Text(timer)
            }
        }
    }.onDisappear(perform: doExit)
}

func doExit() {
    print("-----> TestView doExit")
    // then to go back to the previous view
    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
}
```

Comment: Just tried this out, it works if the sheet is called from a SwiftUI View but when its called using a UIHostingController `self.present(UIHostingController(rootView: TestView(scheduleManager: ["one", "two"])), animated: true, completion: nil)`it won't work.